# Game Results in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlsx, worksheet-function, worksheet

I would much appreciate it if someone could help me with the needed formulas for this case.

I have multiple matches that I want to determine their winners based on their score. I also want to do a couple of stats based on the results.

[A sample of how the game result should be entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey2Om.png)

My requests are:

1- Return winner team name based on the original time result, if a tie then the extra time result, if a tie then penalties result. I also need the winner cell to have no values if no game result is entered.

2- If the game ends in original time, OTC counter increases by 1.

3- If the game ends in extra time, ETC counter increases by 1.

4- If the game ends in penalties, PC counter increases by 1.

I am guessing the counters would be done using the same method but you are the expert here.

Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This information is too big to fit a comment, hence I put it as an answer)

I don't think you'll get answers on this site, as you have not done any effort yourself. But I have the impression that this is due to the fact that you don't know where to start, so let me give you some starting advice.

The functions you'll need to perform this task are mostly `Max()`, `Sum()`, `IF()`, `CountIF()` and maybe `SumIF()` (or `CountIFS()` and `SumIFS()` in case of multiple criteria).

As for the finding of the winner, you might use the `Max()` function in order to find the best result, and use a `Lookup()` function in order to know where you might encounter that result.

It might be helpful to add a helper column, containing a value (like 1) for all winning teams. By adding all those ones, you might fill the information in your other columns.

Now you have a starting point. Please try this out and if you have any specific questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hello Dominique, you are right I didn't know where to start and I thank you for your valuable feedback. I am posting an answer to show my progress so far.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dominique, This is where I got so far regarding deciding on the match winner.

I used a combination of `IF()`, `MAX()` and `LOOKUP` functions. I am now determining results based on 2 cases: original time and penalties.

[This is how the match appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axssV.png)

And this is how my formula looks like to determine the winner

```
=IF(C12=C13,IF(ISBLANK(D13),"",LOOKUP((MAX(D12,D13)),D12:D13,B12:B13)),IF(ISBLANK(C13),"",LOOKUP((MAX(C12,C13)),C12:C13,B12:B13)))
```

My issue now is that I want to count for human error when entering the results. With this formula, it  returns Team B as the winner if the penalties result is a draw which cannot happen. I need it to show an error or not return an output if the result entered in the penalties score are equal.

Thank you for your support.